# Typescript cannot narrow Union based on optional property

Tags: typescript

I've a problem narrowing down a union type in typescript.

Lets assume we have two interfaces and a union:

```js
interface A {
    flag: true
    callback: (arg: string) => void
}

interface B {
    flag?: false
    callback: (arg: number) => void
}

type AB = A | B
```

This gets narrowed down correctly:

```js
const testA: AB = {
    flag: true,
    callback: arg => {
        // typescript knows this is interface A and arg is a string
    }
}

const testB: AB = {
    flag: false,
    callback: arg => {
        // typescript knows this is interface B and arg is a number
    }
}
```

but this won't work:

```js
const testC: AB = {
    // we are implying flag: undefined
    callback: arg => {
        // typescript has no clue if this is A or B
        // arg is implicitly any
    }
}
```

what am I missing?

Here is a link to [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm%20TAGzgHMAuZMKAVwhzwTgIICNEBrcgCjijOQGdKoYgEpkAXgB8yAG4B7YABMsAXyxZQkWIhQAhTHVyESAfnLwC-WnmQMmrBB2Tde5EFQC2zaGKmyFympYYACeAA4oqPriaMgAPsi66ghyIIIUEIKo5FESBjbGfJQ0ADSGtows7OQ8xBLS2DY2APTNFOGZCFDAYWDIbCByAO78FAAWwKOTyJrQ8EixcCCKyLUzo3ACQiDE5WpBKWl9kIK6OdH5eIXmjFZlNnZVjjW89ZdNyK3tEfxdPX0DYajMATKZTcBzHSJVbLVavaabdxeaB7VTJVLpE5gADC5zyjTwXyGKB4KGAHjCBBCwnwRD4VGWEBgoAgygelQcTjWfgJHy%20oR%20f16yDGcFGg1sBBoMxg42m03QcigiVRKiAA)

Thanks in advance

Comment: This may help narrow your question: Typescript actually _is_ determining the correct type of testC as B, as shown in [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/gWoGgW).  So I think your question is really: why doesn't it infer the correct type of the parameter `arg` in `testC.callback`?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Error on testC, [...] 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
const testC: AB = {
  flag: undefined,
  callback: (arg: string) => {
  }
}

// same error
const testC: AB = {
  callback: (arg: string) => {
  }
}
```

Interestingly:

```
interface B {
  flag: false | undefined;
  callback: (arg: number) => void
}

// Type '{ callback: (arg: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'AB'.
//   Property 'flag' is missing in type '{ callback: (arg: any) => void; }' but required in type 'B'.
const testC: AB = {
  callback: (arg) => {
  }
}
```

I am not aware Typescript is supposed to handle `flag?` and `flag: undefined` differently. But might be related to a strange behavior, that peoples are unused to in JS:

```js
Object.keys({a: undefined}); // ['a']
Object.keys({}); // []
```

Answer (score -1):

flag?: declares the possible absence of value.

flag?: false equals to flag: false | undefined, not absence of flag property.

```
const testC: AB = {
    flag: undefined,
    callback: arg => {
        // typescript knows this is interface B and arg is a number
    }
}
```

Comment: If that's the case, why does this compile? `const b : B = { callback: arg => {} }`

Comment: This is wrong; in general `type A<T> = {prop?: T}` is **not** the same type as `type A<T> = {prop: T | undefined}` because in the former `prop` may or may not be an "own" property of `A<T>` values, but in the latter it always is - it just sometimes has the value `undefined`.